# Opening HTML in Vim by Using the Quickrun.vim Plugin

Tags: html, vim, plugins, browser

Is anyone using a Vim plugin called [QuickRun](https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun)?
With it, you can easily run your current code (in many languages) by typing `:QuickRun`. But,how can I run HTML code with it?

I am using Ubuntu. And I realize I can use this `!gnome-open %`, but what about QuickRun?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like if you add

```
let g:quickrun_config = {}
let g:quickrun_config.html = {'command' : 'gnome-open'}
```

to your `.vimrc` it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the blurb, I don't see HTML in the list of supported filetypes. You will need to read the documetation (`:help quickrun`) in order to add support for HTML.

Or use the much much much simpler `!gnome-open %`.

Comment: but it has a good scalability , @Geoff Reedy gives a nice response.why  I not directly use !gnome=open % in .vimrc , cause I wanna got a unified and simple way. sure, thanks for your advice , and I think I should take a look at :h quickrun at now.